# Using numpy.distutils to generate f2py module, module wont work

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Just having some trouble compiling a f2py module for python. I am running windows 10 64-bit with python 3.6 and I used the following code:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension

ext = Extension(name = 'Sigma',
                 sources = ['Sigma.f95'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(name = 'f2py_example',
        ext_modules =[ext])
```

To generate a python module from the following fortran code:

```
subroutine Test(Su, A, B)

real :: A, B, Su 

!f2py intent(in) a
!f2py intent(in) b
!f2pu intent(out) Su

Su = A + B 
end subroutine
```

Which generates a build file with the following file in the `lib.win-amd64-3.6`:

```
Sigma.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
```

Yet when I try to import this then using `Import Sigma` I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\heele\Desktop\Learning Fortran\Plot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Sigma 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Can anyone help me with this? Is it meant to be generating an DLL file that I am missing?

Comment: The library that you generated is one level "below". You can try: 1. set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory `C:\Users\heele\Desktop\Learning Fortran\lib.win-amd64-3.6` 2. Copy the file `Sigma.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` to the same directory as `Plot.py`. (one of the two is enough).

Comment: It’s not working did this work for you?

Comment: I don't have any windows computer so I try to diagnose from the error message you have posted. Did the error change? Did you use the same Python executable to build the extension and to run Plot.py?

Comment: What would you mean by that?

Comment: A possibility for failed import happens when you have several versions of Python installed (i.e. one from Python.org, one from anaconda, etc).